# Using a serializer to validate data in a custom django REST API view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am trying to build a custom API view and I stumbled over 2 problems, one more general, the other one more specific:

I have a custom view where I create a an object from the data sent in the api-request:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def graph_create_view(request):
    """
    """

    network = Network.objects.get(name=request.data["network"])

    graph = Graph.objects.create(
        network_id=network.id,
        name=request.data["name"],
        description=request.data["description"],
        field2==request.data["field"],
        field3==request.data["field"],
        field4==request.data["field"],
        field5==request.data["field"],
        field6==request.data["field"],
        field7==request.data["field"],
    graph.save()

    return Response(HttpResponse.status_code)
```

That works well, when I send all the data specified in the Graph.objects.create method. When I do not send all the data but leave out a field (Let's say I send for example data without the description field) I get a `key`-error. That makes sense, because that key is actually missing. I could circumvent this with many if-else-statements but that is cumbersome, not practical and hard to maintain.

Now, I know I probably should write a generic view and not build this myself like this. The problem is that I need to create a Graph with two nested serializers attached to it and this is quite complicated to implement when overwriting the create method. Because the graph has two more models related to it for which I also create objects and then add it to the graph. Roughly, like this with two models:

```
        new_node = Node.objects.create(
            graph=graph,
            name=data_node["name"],
        )
        new_node.save()
```

My specific question: Is there a way of validating the data or use a serializer in this custom API-view so that the fields I don't send are filled with `None`-values?

My general question: Assuming I'd use a generic API-view, is it recommendable to overwrite the `create`-method when having two nested serializers or what would be the way to go?

Thanks so much in advance, very much appreciate the time, help and insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use DRF serializer to validate the data as well as you can fill with default values.

Assume you have a serializer as follows,

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    foo = serializers.CharField(default='')
    bar = serializers.CharField(default=None)
    foo_bar = serializers.CharField()
```

Here `foo_bar` field id ***required*** (by default), rest of the fields are required too, but in presence of `default` DRF will patch the `default` values.

```
In [2]: s = FooSerializer(data={'foo_bar': 'This is foo_bar'})                                                                                                                                                     

In [3]: s.is_valid()                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[3]: True

In [4]: s.validated_data                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[4]: OrderedDict([('foo', ''), ('bar', None), ('foo_bar', 'This is foo_bar')])
```

Here **`.validated_data`** is used in the **`create()`** method of Serializer class. You can see, `foo` and `bar` fields are filled with the `default` values we have provided in the serializer definition.

---

> Assuming I'd use a generic API-view, is it recommendable to overwrite the create-method when having two nested serializers or what would be the way to go?

We have two create methods,

1. `create()` method of **`viewsets.ModelViewSet`**
2. `create()` method of **`serializer.Serializer`** (or its subclasses)

Overriding the `create()` method of serializer is the DRF way to handle ***writable nested serializers***.

Comment: That my friend, was extremely helpful!! Thank you so much! Short follow up: Is it very bad practice to build a custom api view like I do? I mean yes, better to do it generically, but will I run into many problems with a custom implementation?

Comment: Most of the APIs are used to do CRUD operations and I only see a ***create operation*** in your view. If your requirement is to handle a CRUD operation, go for `ModelViewSet` which is defined for CRUD operations

Answer (score 1):

if 'your_key' not in request.data.keys():
    # do whatever you want

Comment: Thanks for your help SST. This is what I meant when I said "I could circumvent this with many if-else-statements but that is cumbersome, not practical and hard to maintain." I could look up all the fields but let's say I add another field then I have to adapt everything again. I was looking to reuse some of the generic stuff django provides. But thank you, this works too.